# Trying to assign repeated fields same values as non-repeated fields

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to order the output of a query which extracts all URLs present in a row to a repeated field - the original rows contained anything between 0 - 20 URLs.

This was my initial query and it worked great at extracting every URL.

```
SELECT
Unique_ID, Content, Col_C, Col_D, 
REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(Content, r'(?i:(?:(?:(?:ftp|https?):\/\/)(?:www\.)?|www\.)(?:[\da-z-_\.]+)(?:[a-z\.]{2,7})(?:[\/\w\.-_\?\&]*)*\/?)') AS URL
FROM
  Project.Table_1
```

However, where there are many URLs per row, the new column, 'URL' only attaches the values of other columns to the first row of a repeated result. I'm looking to get a new row created for each unique URL instead, with a repeat of of the values in the 'Content' Column. This is so I can reattach values which have been human coded in Col_C, Col_D, etc to each individual URL when I wish to query them later.

Ideally, this is how I'd like things to look.

Initial result:

```
Unique_ID     Content    Col_C      Col_D       URL
001           abc         efg        hij        www.facebook.com 
002           zxy         qwe        rty        www.facebook.com
                                                www.bbc.co.uk
                                                www.nbc.com


Desired output:
Unique_ID     Content    Col_C      Col_D       URL
001           abc         efg        hij        www.facebook.com 
002           zxy         qwe        rty        www.facebook.com
002           zxy         qwe        rty        www.bbc.co.uk                                                 002           zxy         qwe        rty        www.nbc.com
```

Hope that all makes sense!

Any help on this would be really appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
  Unique_ID, Content, Col_C, Col_D, URL     
FROM (
  SELECT Unique_ID, Content, Col_C, Col_D, 
    REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(Content, r'(?i:(?:(?:(?:ftp|https?):\/\/)(?:www\.)?|www\.)(?:[\da-z-_\.]+)(?:[a-z\.]{2,7})(?:[\/\w\.-_\?\&]*)*\/?)') AS URL
  FROM Project.Table_1
), UNNEST(URL) as URL
```